# Is there any way we can Modify The Product Edit Page in Shopify Admin Dashboard?

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app

We are trying to build an app for Shopify That can work Like ShopifyFD Chrome Extension. What it does actually is that it creates some extra options in the product edit page in the admin dashboard.
Why do we want this?
We want the same functionality of extension in Shopify webkul the Multi-Vendor App so we are trying to build an app that will integrate with that too 
At last, We want a Product Comparison page that compares the products by these features?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the Shopify UI in any way with an App.

You will have to use a browser extension or bookmarklet.